# Firebird SQL using <if> in <where>

Tags: stored-procedures, if-statement, firebird, where-clause, clause

I try to construct a SP in FB 2.5 that looks like that:

```
where 
   (
      (kunde between :kdvon and :kdbis)
      and 
          (AdrGrp between :AdrGrpvon and :AdrGrpbis)
      and
          (auftragstyp between :AuftrTypVon and :AuftrTypBis)
      and
          (Status between :statusvon and :statusbis)
      and
      IF LFDNR <> 0 THEN (LFDNUMMER  = :LFDNR)
      IF BESTELLTAG <> 0 then (bestelldatum  = :BESTELLTAG)
   )
```

It worked well until the If Statements were inserted.
After that I get the message
    SQL error code = -104.
    Token unknown - line 156, column 14.
    LFDNR.

The IF conditions are defined as Input Parameters. Using the colon : to mark them as parameters did not work.

Question
Is it possible to use "If" inside "Where" in this way?
How do I have to use the condidional params?

TiA
Rolf

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
...
AND (LFNDR = 0 OR LFDNUMMER = :LFDNR)
AND (BESTELLTAG = 0 OR bestelldatum = :BESTELLTAG)
```

(I don't know if `LFNDR` and `BESTELLTAG` are parameters/variables or columns in the `= 0` clause - if they are parameters (the same as the right hand part), you should probably mark them with a ':')

Comment: I had to remove the standard values used:<br/>              and (:LFDNR is null or LFDNUMMER = :LFDNR)</br> works fine . Thank you very much.

Comment: the 0 or '' values were not casted correctly (got another error about that). As they were set to "nothing" anyway, I deleted the standard values. So these params have null values (if no value is passed) and I can test against null or a value. That works fine.

Comment: You didn't specify what data type the parameters were. They probably aren't comparable to `0`. Null is a better option than 0 anyway for "not specified" IMHO, so I believe you made a good choice.